# Django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library ,Is GDAL installed?

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-18.04, gdal

This comes from the continuation of my question here :

[error in GDAL setup command: use_2to3 is invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75672211/error-in-gdal-setup-command-use-2to3-is-invalid)

Since the nature of error has changed, its important to post it separately.
I'm running Django rest api with the django 3.2 on GCPUbuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm facing a problem when I run docker-compose command. The trace points to Gdal

Because of conflicts between setuptools==67.6.0 and gdal==2.4.2 and causing the previous error in the linked question (which isn't solved), I attempted the following :

I removed gdal package in requirements.txt and used the following :

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev
pip3 install GDAL==$(gdal-config --version | awk -F'[.]' '{print $1"."$2}')
```

The above shows to use legacy setup.py and it recognized gdal-config version to be 2.4 (rather than 2.4.2) and installed it.

Now when I run docker-compose and the containers I get the following :

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not find the GDAL library (tried "gdal", "GDAL", "gdal3.1.0", "gdal3.0.0", "gdal2.4.0", "gdal2.3.0", "gdal2.2.0", "gdal2.1.0", "gdal2.0.0"). Is GDAL installed? If it is, try setting GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH in your settings.
```

setuptools for other packages remains at 67.6.0 while gdal is separately installed (not from requirements.txt) using a legacy installer.

I have already tried :

```
sudo apt install libgdal-dev --upgrade
sudo apt-get install gdal-bin --upgrade
```

which are solutions mentioned for user facing a similar problem.

EDIT :
Based on recommendation of @phd,
Adding GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH to my settings.py after referring to the post :
https://github.com/moose46/Jobbee/blob/master/backend/backend/settings.py#L156
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdal-library-path

Proposed solution :

```
VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE = os.environ.get("ENVIRONMENT")
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = VIRTUAL_ENV_BASE + "/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal304.dll"
```

However ,
The following is inside osgeo folder,gdal304.dll isnt there.

[image: osgeo folder inside site-packages]

Getting the following trace now after running docker-compose:

```
OSError: development/home/earthling/myEnv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/osgeo/gdal304.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

EDIT : 12/03/2023
After adding

```
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20.5.2"
```

Getting the following trace :

```html
my-api-webserver | Traceback (most recent call last):
my-api-webserver |   File "manage.py", line 25, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
my-api-webserver |     utility.execute()
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 395, in execute
my-api-webserver |     django.setup()
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
my-api-webserver |     apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
my-api-webserver |     app_config.import_models()
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 301, in import_models
my-api-webserver |     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
my-api-webserver |     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
my-api-webserver |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
my-api-webserver |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
my-api-webserver |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
my-api-webserver |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
my-api-webserver |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
my-api-webserver |   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
my-api-webserver |   File "/opt/my-api/kosmosnetwork_socialcommerce/src/commerce/apps/stores/models.py", line 3, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from . import abstract_models
my-api-webserver |   File "/opt/my-api/kosmosnetwork_socialcommerce/src/commerce/apps/stores/abstract_models.py", line 1, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.db.models import Manager, PointField
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     import django.contrib.gis.db.models.functions  # NOQA
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/functions.py", line 3, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.db.models.fields import BaseSpatialField, GeometryField
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/db/models/fields.py", line 3, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis import forms, gdal
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from .fields import (  # NOQA
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/forms/fields.py", line 2, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.gdal import GDALException
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.datasource import DataSource
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/datasource.py", line 40, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.driver import Driver
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/driver.py", line 5, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.prototypes import ds as vcapi, raster as rcapi
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/prototypes/ds.py", line 9, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     from django.contrib.gis.gdal.libgdal import GDAL_VERSION, lgdal
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/contrib/gis/gdal/libgdal.py", line 50, in <module>
my-api-webserver |     lgdal = CDLL(lib_path)
my-api-webserver |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 373, in __init__
my-api-webserver |     self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
my-api-webserver | OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20.5.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
my-api-webserver exited with code 1
```

Comment: "*recognized gdal-config version to be 2.4 (rather than 2.4.2)*" Because that what you output in `awk '{print $1"."$2}'`

Comment: @phd. Thank you for pointing that out. Can you please help me with the issue above if you could ?

Comment: May be it needs `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdal.so"` in `settings.py`? https://stackoverflow.com/a/67140709/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured%3A+Could+not+find+the+GDAL+library

Comment: Sure. Will try the above and update.

Comment: Hi @phd. Getting this now after updating & running my docker containers : "OSError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, in bionic 18.04 it's [`/usr/lib/libgdal.so`](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/libgdal-dev/filelist).

Comment: GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/libgdal.so" . Getting Same:"OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". I checked whether the file is there an it is there ! wonder what is wrong.

Comment: [That's](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/#gdal-library-path) it. [Example](https://github.com/moose46/Jobbee/blob/master/backend/backend/settings.py#L156).

Comment: Have updated the quesion pls check. the .dll file isnt there in my folder osgeo

Comment: @phd getting the same error. this time with pointing to the dll file

Comment: Hello @phd. Any thoughts on what could be done ?

Comment: Do you understand that extension `.dll` is for a different OS? That is, the example that I showed was only an example, not a code to blindly copy. You need to find `libgdal.so` at you system; is it `/usr/lib/libgdal.so`? If `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib/libgdal.so"` in `settings.py` doesn't help I'm out of ideas. Perhaps there should be a table what version of GDAL to use with what version of GeoDjango so after installing GDAL you need to downgrade Django but I don't know to what version.

Comment: Hi@phd. well I have erred there. I'm a newbie , maybe not a advanced user like you.

Comment: GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = os.path.join("/usr/lib/libgdal.so") is what i tried now. The error that comes is : OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: You don't need `os.path.join()` with exactly 1 component; `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib/libgdal.so"` is enough. But first — is it there? `ls -l /usr/lib/libgdal.so` in command line.

Comment: HI I got the following result "lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 17 Jul 14  2019 /usr/lib/libgdal.so -> libgdal.so.20.5.2"

Comment: So either `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib/libgdal.so"` or `GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = "/usr/lib/libgdal.so.20.5.2"` should work. If doesn't work — it's most probably versioning problem: either up/downgrade `libdgal-dev` or GeoDjango.

Comment: Sure. we try out downgrading because even 20.5.2 at the every end gives the same issue.

Comment: Updated the question with the detailed trace just for the record. Also i'm looking to downgrade libgdal-dev first and GeoDjango. Any help for the versions would be helpful.

Comment: I'm currently on Ubuntu 18.04. would upgrading Ubuntu to 22.04 work. Here is the list of libgdal-dev packages. https://pkgs.org/download/libgdal-dev

Comment: I upgraded to ubuntu 22.05 LTS. now gdal config --version == 3.4.1 and so is the package gdal installed through pip. Getting the same  "OSError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Comment: @phd have uploaded it as a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75718063/oserror-usr-lib-libgdal-so-cannot-open-shared-object-file-no-such-file-or-di

Comment: Hi @phd. Could you help me here if possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75733558/django-db-utils-notsupportederror-extension-postgis-is-not-available